# Regex pattern java with commas

Tags: java, regex

I have a below string which comes from an excel column

```
  "\"USE CODE \"\"Gef, sdf\"\" FROM 1/7/07\""
```

I would like to set regex pattern to retrieve the entire string,so that my result would be exactly like

```
"USE CODE ""Gef, sdf"" FROM 1/7/07"
```

Below is what I tried

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches
{
    public static void main( String args[] ){

      // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
      String line = "\"USE CODE \"\"Gef, sdf\"\" FROM 1/7/07\", Delete , Hello , How are you ? , ";
      String line2 = "Test asda ds asd, tesat2 . test3";

      String dpattern = "(\"[^\"]*\")(?:,(\"[^\"]*\"))*,|([^,]+),";
      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern d = Pattern.compile(dpattern);
      Matcher md = d.matcher(line2);

      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(dpattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      if (m.find( )) {
         System.out.println("Found value: 0 " + m.group(0) );
       //  System.out.println("Found value: 1 " + m.group(1) );
         //System.out.println("Found value: 2 " + m.group(2) );
      } else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
      }
   }
}
```

and the result out of it breaks after ,(comma) and hence the output is

```
Found value: 0 "USE CODE ""Gef,
```

It should be

```
Found value: 0 "USE CODE ""Gef sdf"" FROM 1/7/07",
```

and for the second line `Matcher m = r.matcher(line2);` the output should be

```
Found value: 0 "Test asda ds asd",
```

Comment: Note: In the real scenario,I cannot manipulate on the given string like removing the quotes and then apply regex. All I can do is to get it via Regex pattern .So this java is to test the regex pattern .

Comment: im not sure what your trying to do with the non capturing group `?:` and the OR operator `|`, but it looks like you could just use `(\"[^\"]*\"){3}` and it would match 3 quoted groups.

Comment: Do you mean you need to get the double quoted substring only? Like [`"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"`](https://regex101.com/r/bD5qO0/1)? What is the expected output for the line1 and line 2? Maybe [`(?:"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"|[^,])+`](https://regex101.com/r/bD5qO0/4) might do?

Comment: Why not select simply everything between two `\"`? like `\".*\"`. You can do a pre computation check of validity string assuring that `\"` is a pair number in order to avoid false positives.

Comment: With Matcher m = r.matcher(line); the output should be: Found value: 0 "USE CODE ""Gef, sdf"" FROM 1/7/07",

With Matcher m = r.matcher(line2); the output should be: Found value: 0 "Test asda ds asd",

Comment: See http://ideone.com/1AOvhZ - I just modified it to return the first match. Does it work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Works perfect ! Thanks a lot

Comment: Added as an answer then with explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"|[^,])+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bD5qO0/4)

**Explanation**:

- `"` - leading quote
- `[^"]*` - 0+ chars other than a double quote
- `(?:""[^"]*)*` - 0+ sequences of a `""` text followed with 0+ chars other than a double quote
- `"` - trailing quote

OR:

- `[^,]` - any char but a comma

And the whole pattern is matched 1 or more times as it is enclosed with `(?:...)+` and `+` matches 1 or more occurrences.

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/1AOvhZ):

```
String line = "\"USE CODE \"\"Gef, sdf\"\" FROM 1/7/07\", Delete , Hello , How are you ? , ";
String line2 = "Test asda ds asd, tesat2 . test3";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\"[^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*\"|[^,])+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
if (matcher.find()){                        // if is used to get the 1st match only
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
}
Matcher matcher2 = pattern.matcher(line2); 
if (matcher2.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher2.group(0)); 
}
```